# Getting javascript wrapper error in Qcodo PHP Framework

Tags: qcodo

Seem to be getting an error but can't figure out how to drill down further.  Typically use Firebug to figure-out JavaScript:

The referenced file post.js can be found here:

http://github.com/allyforce/AF-upload/blob/master/assets/js/_core/post.js

[alt text http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/3180/screenshot29201013619pm.png](http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/3180/screenshot29201013619pm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to reference a control you didn't render. This is often done by accident when people tell it to render a QDialog, but have the dialog set to Visible=false (don't send to browser) rather than Display=false (set CSS style to display:none).

Comment: Or just set the Display property on the object in the underlying PHP code that instantiates the control